# href attribute is not working on button as well as on menu

Tags: html, css

I want to know why href attribute on "Get started" button on index.html is not working. They have used href with correct Ids still it is not working.

Here is the link of the web page: http://www.free-css.com/free-css-templates/page189/romna

Answer (score -1):

All links `href="#block"` not work, maybe because site use custom `ease scroll to href`. JS blocking it,  try delete js

Comment: want me to delete custom js?